# How to initialize inherited object's fields

Tags: go

I must be missing something.  I cannot initialize an object's inherited fields without directly accessing them.

My goal is trying to keep it simple.

```
package main

type Page struct {
  Title string
}

type Article struct {
  Page
  Id int
}

func main() {

  // this generates a build error: 
  // "invalid field name Title in struct initializer"
  //
  p := &Article{
    Title: "Welcome!",
    Id:    2,
  }

  // this generates a build error: 
  // "invalid field name Page.Title in struct initializer"
  //
  p := &Article{
    Page.Title: "Welcome!",
    Id:         2,
  }

  // this works, but is verbose...  trying to avoid this
  //
  p := &Article{
    Id:    2,
  }
  p.Title = "Welcome!"

  // as well as this, since the above was just a shortcut
  //
  p := &Article{
    Id:    2,
  }
  p.Page.Title = "Welcome!"

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Go, these fields from embedded structs are called **promoted** fields.

[The Go Specification states](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) (my emphasis):

> Promoted fields act like ordinary fields of a struct *except that they cannot be used as field names in composite literals* of the struct.

This is how you can solve it:

```
p := &Article{
    Page: Page{"Welcome!"},
    Id:   2,
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to init like this:

```
p := &Article{
    Page: Page{
        Title: "Welcome!",
    },
    Id: 2,
}
```

PlayGround: http://play.golang.org/p/CEUahBLwCT

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Page struct {
    Title string
}

type Article struct {
    Page
    Id int
}

func main() {

    // this generates a build error:
    // "invalid field name Title in struct initializer"
    //
    p := &Article{
        Page: Page{
            Title: "Welcome!",
        },
        Id: 2,
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v \n", p)
}
```

Comment: thanks.  since the first answer i commented on already had it, I'll accept his.